# Table dimensions not the same across instances

Tags: tables, minipage, layout

I'm building (with some python magic behind) a report with multiple tables on the same page. Each one must have the same overall width, but they have a different number of columns.

By specifying the columns width with `m{Xcm}`, I'm expecting the overall width of a table being the same, **as long as the sum of all the columns width is equal**.

In practice my 3 tables have not the same width, and I don't know where this comes from.

Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}[]{|m{1cm} | m{14cm} |} \hline \vspace{4pt} \texttt{Title} &
            \vspace{4pt} \texttt{Description} \\[4pt] \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}{|m{3cm}|m{3cm}|m{3cm}|m{3cm}|m{3cm}|}\hline
             1 &  2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ 
            \scriptsize{Minor} &
            \scriptsize{Low} &
            \scriptsize{High} &
            \scriptsize{Medium} &
            \scriptsize{Easy} \\ \hline         
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{|m{15cm}|} \hline
        \vspace{3pt} \textbf{Description:} 
        \url{https://www.google.com}
        \\[3pt] \hline
        \vspace{3pt} \parbox[t]{15cm}{ \textbf{More info :} 
        Long text about something   
        } \vspace{3pt} \\ \hline
        \vspace{3pt} \textbf{Target :} 
        More text again
        \\[3pt] \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{|m{15cm}|} \hline   
        \textbf{Conclusion :} \\
        Conclusion text
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And it produces this : [image: MWE]

All the small tables are in total 15cm :

- 1cm + 14cm
- 5 x 3cm
- 15cm

What can I make to have all those `tabular` having the same size ?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but a different approach would be to have one table with six columns and then use multicolumn to merge some of those columns.

Comment: you need to take account of `\tabcolsep` padding either side of each column, and `\arrayrulewidth`  width of the vertical rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking into account the `tabcolsep` asn `arraywidth`s (as [already mentioned by David Carlisle in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517118/table-dimensions-not-the-same-across-instances#comment1307731_517118)), you end up with the following MWE and output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}[]{|m{1cm-2\tabcolsep} | m{14cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth} |} \hline \vspace{4pt} \texttt{Title} &
            \vspace{4pt} \texttt{Description} \\[4pt] \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{tabular}{|m{3cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|m{3cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|m{3cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|m{3cm-2\tabcolsep-\arrayrulewidth}|m{3cm-2\tabcolsep}|}\hline
             1 &  2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ 
            \scriptsize{Minor} &
            \scriptsize{Low} &
            \scriptsize{High} &
            \scriptsize{Medium} &
            \scriptsize{Easy} \\ \hline         
        \end{tabular}
    \begin{tabular}{|m{15cm-2\tabcolsep}|} \hline
        \vspace{3pt} \textbf{Description:} 
        \url{https://www.google.com}
        \\[3pt] \hline
        \vspace{3pt} \parbox[t]{15cm}{ \textbf{More info :} 
        Long text about something   
        } \vspace{3pt} \\ \hline
        \vspace{3pt} \textbf{Target :} 
        More text again
        \\[3pt] \hline
    \end{tabular}

    \begin{tabular}{|m{15cm-2\tabcolsep}|} \hline   
        \textbf{Conclusion :} \\
        Conclusion text
        \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However, this MWE produces an output with quite a lot of flaws: First of all, the tables are wider than the textwidth, which will result in an overflow into the right margin and a bunch of overfull box warnings. Also, the "Title"  column is now too narrow for the word to fit. Lastly, the column declaration part got a lot longer and less readable.

Therefore I'd prefer using `tabularx` in combination with `cellspace` as shown in the following MWE and output:

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\noindent
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|Sl|S{X}|}
        \hline 
        \texttt{Title} & \texttt{Description} \\
        \hline
        \end{tabularx}
\noindent
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{5}{X|}}\hline
             1 &  2 & 3 & 4 & 5  \\ 
            \scriptsize{Minor} &
            \scriptsize{Low} &
            \scriptsize{High} &
            \scriptsize{Medium} &
            \scriptsize{Easy} \\ \hline         
        \end{tabularx}
\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|S{X}|} 
        \hline
        \textbf{Description:} \url{https://www.google.com} \\
        \hline
        \textbf{More info :} Long text about something \\ 
        \hline
        \textbf{Target :} More text again  \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\noindent
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|} 
        \hline   
        \textbf{Conclusion :} \\
        Conclusion text \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```